# How do we compute $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{K^{Sn}}$, for $K$ an integer and $S$ a complex number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Consider the series: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{K^{Sn}}$$

where $K$ is some integer constant and $S$ is a complex number.

How we evaluate (compute sum of) this series where S is a complex number. Can we use integration? (I am unsure how we will do that as S is a complex number.)

Can someone please help with the formula? I am new to complex analysis thus struggling.

Comment: Write $s=K^S$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}s^{-n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a geometric progression with quotient $1/K^S$.

Comment: Indeed it is. So, can we simply evaluate the sum as: $1/(1-r)$ where $r=1/K^S$ ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot...